# Simple Fractal square

Tags: graphics, recursion, fractals, iteration

I am working on a math question about infinite series, and one of the question images is below.

[image: iterations of subdividing a square]

Each new white square has an area that is 1/4 of the previous square.

Always looking to learn elegant ways to create things using Mathematica,  and in this case, probably recursion as well?

I know it's not complicated, but any help with the process would be appreciated.

Having a NICE diagram really helps with creating a better response.
(questions about sums of areas of white, black, etc.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
coords = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}};
tf = Composition[TranslationTransform[{1/2, 0}], ScalingTransform[{1/2, 1/2}]]
n = 4;
rects = NestList[tf /@ # &, coords, n];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[], White, Polygon[Most/@rects], Polygon@Last@rects}]
```

[image]

```
Row @ Table[With[{rects = NestList[tf /@ # &, coords, n]}, 
 Graphics[{ EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[], White, 
  Polygon[Most /@ rects], Polygon @ Last @ rects}, ImageSize -> 200]], {n, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: I used this answer to create a "Manipulate",  SUPER useful for creating some help the student needed with this question.  Can't even compare with the original diagram,  having this was perfect.

Comment: @TomDeVries, really glad it was useful. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 9):

```
n = 100;
T1 = Developer`ToPackedArray[{{-1., 0.}, {-0.5, 0.}, {-0.5, 0.5}}];
T2 = Developer`ToPackedArray[{{-0.5, 0.5}, {0., 0.5}, {0., 1.}}];
Graphics[{
  Polygon[Table[0.5^k T1, {k, 0, n}]],
  Polygon[Table[0.5^k T2, {k, 0, n}]]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: That is so concise,  unbelievable!

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @HenrikSchumacher:

```
Graphics@NestList[Scale[#, 1/2, {0, 0}] &, 
  Polygon[{{{-2, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}}, {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}}}], 10]
```

> [image]

This can be also shortened to:

```
Graphics@NestList[Scale[#, 1/2, {0, 0}] &, 
  Polygon[{{-2, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}}], 10]
```